# Imports in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to customize the auto formatting of imports?

[make of this kind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2LE8.png)

[Here is the format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK5X7.png)

I thought prettier would help me

Comment: Just write the import like in second image

Comment: VS-Code formatting options are described briefly here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_formatting .

Comment: You can write your own formatter if the existing formatters don't support your expected format.

Comment: Please read [ask]: _"DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vs code includes a default code formatter for typescript , to keep all the imports in the same line , use it with :   right click > format document with > functionality of typescript and javascript languages

if you mean a formatter to switch between image 2 and image 1, you will need to write your own formatter

Comment: It's clear, so I'll have to write my own formatter. Thanks for the answer